# How to preserve my session in PHP?

Tags: php, html, session, authentication, post

I'm making video-portal, so I've authentication system and if I post some comment, or image sessions disapper.
And i Get "Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_site\assets\login.php on line 2"
AND "Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_site\assets\login.php on line 3
".

login.php

```html
<?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $hash_password = $row['password'];
    $hash = password_verify( $password, $hash_password);
    $y = $_session['username'] = $row['username'];
    $x = $_session['id'] = $row['id'];


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if ($hash == 0) {
    header('location: index.php?fillpassword');
    exit();
  }
  else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email' AND password='$hash_password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


    if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "<script>alert('You have no access here. You must login.')</script>";
      header ("Location: ../index.php?erorr=noaccess");
      }
    }
  }


 ?>
```

main.php

```html
<?php
if ($_SESSION['id'] = $row['id']) {
                  echo "<form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='size' value='1000000'>
                    <input type='file' name='image' value='Upload photo'>
                    <textarea name='text' rows='8' cols='80'></textarea>
                    <br/>
                    <input type='submit' name='upload' value='Submit'>
                    </form>";
                  }
                  
                  ?>
```

Comment: Add `session_start();` as the first line of code in all php files which require the use of session variables

Comment: Add session_start on the pages that needs session variables

Comment: I have session_start in my main.php file.
If I add session_start() in login.php I get "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_site\assets\login.php on line 2"

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a [session_start](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at the begin of your script.
If you don't want to have php's warning when the session is destroyed add also a check to see if the session is still there:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['password')){ [..] }
```

Comment: I have session_start in my main.php file. If I add session_start() in login.php I get "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_site\assets\login.php on line 2" –

Comment: check if the session is not already started with if(session_id() == "" ), and then run session_start()

Comment: My main.php
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';
include 'assets/login.php';
include 'comment.php';

?>

Comment: and that is on the start of the script?

Comment: Yes. 
If i "post" submit in comment section my sessions disappear.

Comment: and your comment.php? does it have a session_start?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used dreamweaver , the dreamweaver add hidden some charackters, you can check or remove it by HXD software . [Download it from here](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) .